# How to increment a pointer inside a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

To increment a pointer that points to an array, we do `*(p+i)` or `*(p++)` but how do I increment a pointer that is inside of a linked list? 
I have this struct:

```
typedef struct list carPilot, *pCarPilot;
struct list{
    pilot pilot;
    car car;
    int *time;
    pCarPilot prox;
};

struct race {
    int laps;     
    int size;    
    int n_cars;   
};

/* ------------------ */

int times[race.cars][race.laps];
pCarPilot list = NULL;

for(j = 0; j < race.laps; j++) {
     times[i][j] = calculaSegundos(idade,peso,exp,potencia,caract.comprimento); 
     *(list->time+ j) = times[i][j];  // my error is HERE
}
```

I'd tried to do `*(list->time + i)` and `*(list->time ++)` but when I run the code, the program just stops.

Comment: That works on arrays as arrays are layed out sequentially in memory. But linked lists are not guaranteed to be that way. So you can't do that.

Comment: To increment a pointer inside a linked list, you need a loop that follows the `prox` pointers.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It'd be helpful to post a [mcve] for this which illustrates your code that is crashing.

Comment: Please, could you clearify whether you want to get the next **pilot**'s time or the next (lap?) **time** of the same pilot? In any case, how have you allocated the memory for `time`?

Comment: @Bob__ What I want to do is: I have 4 pilots for 5 laps in a linked list and each node has the pointer `*time`. Then, I want to go through all the array with the `aux->time` and in each node has 5 different times that are recorded on another array.

Comment: Why is something like `time` a pointer in the first place? That seems like a very strange design. It's just a number. Unless that's an array of *N* times, it's not worth the fuss.

Comment: @tadman Yes it's a pointer to an array with 5 times

Comment: Well, if you know the exact number (compile time constant) of laps, you could use an array inside the struct: `int time[N_LAPS];`. On the other hand, you already have `times` which seems to store the lap times of each car, so I'm not sure to follow your data structure choices.

Comment: I can't use a static array because the number of laps it's not fixed, it's asked to the user to input a value between 5 and 10. What I want to do is copy from the `times[race.cars][race.laps]` to the correct pilot in each node. The bidimensional array has 20 times, and I want to split each 5 for each node.

Comment: This is missing a *lot* of code, especially with how things are allocated. Normally you'd do `list->time[n] = x` where `n` is your index and `x` is your value, but this depends on that list being the correct size, and 0 <= `n` < S where `S` is the list size.

Comment: Where are you `malloc`ing memory for `int *time` before you dereference it?

Comment: `*(list->time+ j)` is better and more clearly written as `list->time[j]`.

Answer (score 1):

Given that your structs are probably created as multiple malloc call, they are most likely distributed across memory.

Imagine memory for an array. It's laid out like that:

```
 p
-----------
|0|1|2|3|4|
-----------
```

so you can call `*(p + 3)` to access a nearby value

For dynamically allocated structs, it's most likely something like

```
 p
---------------------------
|0|other thing|1|a|2|etc..|
---------------------------
```

So `*(p + 2)` is inside `other thing`, which is not what you'd expect.

The work around is that linked list have a pointer inside them; so for example `list->prox` should be the next instance. No need to touch the pointers directly.

---

On a side note, your carPilot is itself a type; thus you should not add int before it.

Comment: yeah, but imagine that before doing the `list->prox` I want to go through all the array with the pointer and after that I do the `list->prox`. In this case, I have 4 pilots for 5 laps, and I want to save all the 5 times in the node and after that I do `list->prox`.

Comment: @whoami are your inner arrays ever initialized? Seems like Bob__ might be right, since from the snippet provided you never even initialize time